# How to set character encode in workbook, sheet and cells of HSSF Classes in Apache POI beyond 3.7 version?

Tags: java, character-encoding, apache-poi

It seems that the character-encoding methods for the HSSF Excel Classes have been taken out from the 3.8 release. I really need to specify the enconding on at least the cells. The API does not even register the encoding methods any more, not even as deprecated, they have left the static fields of encoding, though.

¿How to set encoding in new POI versions?

Comment: Why do you need to set the encoding? Why can't you just pass in a (Unicode) String and have POI handle it all for you automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, there is a method for doing this from your code for what ever your needs may be:

```
//Create the workbook, and the font
HSSFWorkbook wb;
HSSFFont wbFont;
wbFont=wb.createFont();
wbFont.setCharSet(HSSFFont.ANSI_CHARSET); //Your Character encoding goes in the parameter
//Establish cell styles
HSSFCellStyle cellStyle =wb.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setFont(wbFont);
//We create our cells with our data and with our specified format
HSSFCell cell =null;
cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
cell.setCellValue("MY DATA");
//Do the rest of work for your workbook and then you create it
```

Remember, these classes only work with .xls 2003